# Simpler Proof Regarding a Deleted Neighborhood

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I saw a proof demonstrating that a deleted neighborhood is an open set, but I could not help but think of how convoluted and, in my opinion, how unnecessarily complicated it was. However, that opinion came to me because I believe the proof that I constructed below is simpler, assuming it is correct. So, I would like for it to be reviewed in case I made an error in argumentation. I really appreciate anyone's valid input.

To prove that a deleted neighborhood $N^*(x;\epsilon)$ for an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ is an open set, I proceed as follows.

Note: $N^*(x;\epsilon) = (x-\epsilon,x) \cup (x, x+\epsilon)$.

Consider the open intervals $(x-\epsilon,x)$ and $(x, x+\epsilon)$. Clearly these sets are open sets, because they do not contain their respective boundary points. Because the union of any collection of open sets is open, the union $(x-\epsilon,x) \cup (x, x+\epsilon)$ is open, therefore, $N^*(x;\epsilon)$ is open.

Comment: That might work for the real line, it doesn't work for an arbitrary metric space....

Comment: okay. I just started real analysis. I'm in the section of Steven R. Lay's book, "Analysis with an introduction to proof." I'm in section 3.4 entitled, "Topology of the Real Numbers." This section defines neighborhoods in terms of intervals, rather than in terms of a ball in metric spaces.

Comment: It is likely the book's proof is more complicated to make it easier to move it to the more general case, however.

Comment: Okay, great. That will be good to keep in mind when I finally transition to metric spaces, which is what I think you're referring to in your last comment.